# How to fix jquery/javascript value is not showing 2nd time in html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use year multiple times in an HTML page using the below script

```
$('#year').text(new Date().getFullYear());
```

It is getting displayed first time but 2nd time it is not working. I am using below code in html

```
<p>Copyright &copy;
  First Time<span id="year"></span> - Second Time<span id="year"></span>
</p>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
  <title>Jquery Date issue</title>
</head>
<body> 
    <p>Copyright &copy;
            First Time<span id="year"></span> - Second Time<span id="year"></span>
    </p>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script>
    // Get the current year for the copyright
    $('#year').text(new Date().getFullYear());   
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

The code is here https://jsfiddle.net/vptechworld/z0gmobyw/5/

Comment: An "id" value must be *unique* on the page. Also your first `<p>` should be inside, not outside, the document.

Comment: Thanks got it @Pointy

Answer (score 0):

You can not have two elements with same ID, but you can use same class.

```
<p>Copyright &copy;
  First Time<span class="year"></span> - Second Time<span class="year"></span>
</p>
```

```js
$('.year').text(new Date().getFullYear());
```

Comment: thanks got it @tobias